# Change the value of object in an array on click event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

How can I change the value of an array from inside a `map` function using button `onClick` event. In the following example I defined and array name `visitMyArray` that has three objects and initially the value of `visited` key is set as `false`. Using `map` function I render the all the `location` inside a `paragraph` tag. There will be a `button` rendered for each `paragraph`. Is it possible to change the value of the `visited` from `false` to `true` if possible how can I do it.

```
import React from "react";
import {Button} from 'react-bootstrap';

class VisitComponent extends React.Component {

render(){
    let visitmyArray = [
        {
            location:"Indiana",
            visited:false
        },
        {
            location:"Illinoi",
            visited:false
        },
        {
            location:"Ohio",
            visited:false
        }
    ]
    return(
      <div>
        {visitmyArray.map((visitedArray, index) => {
             <div key={index}>
                <p>{visitedArray.location}</p>
                <Button onClick={"Change the visited value from 'false' to 'true' for this object value"}>Continue</Button>
             </div>
            )})}
      </div>
   }
}

export default VisitComponent
```

Comment: `visitmyArray.map((visitedArray, index) => {` <- this is bad. `visitedArray` is an element of an array, not an array.

Answer (score 3):

You can set the `visited` property to `true` for each item on the map. Your `onClick` now would be

```
onClick={() => {visitedArray.visited = true}}
```

Comment: This is in react though, so he might want to do that with a `this.setState` call

Comment: @TKoL visitmyArray  is not part of state here

Comment: I agree with @pbialy. `visitmyArray` is not declared as a state inside of `constructor()`. It is declared on `render()`, making it pointless to call `this.setState()`

Comment: @TKoL you are right I'm not using state here. I indent to do it without state

Comment: Answer update: I have changed the value to `true` as giving it a `!visitedArray.visited` will perform a 'toggle' effect.

Comment: @RhaidzsalAli this updates the visitedArray right. Once the visited array updates visitMyArray also will be updated?

Comment: Exactly, and only for the selected item that the `visited` property will be set to `true`. The remaining objects on the array will remain as is, unless if they are clicked.

Comment: @LalasM but nothing happening here seemingly will allow you to display the 'visited' property after it changes. You sure you want that? You want to change the property of an element in an array, with no way of displaying that in the UI?

Comment: @TKoL You said it exactly im trying to give a conditional styling as per the 'visted' value update. I'm not able to do it. That is what I'm trying to do now but the style is not applied event the visited  value is updated. Thanks for looking more in to it

Comment: That's probably because you should be using `state`. That's why I brought up `setState` to begin with. Using state will make it easier to have a visually updating component in this case.

Comment: You can have a functional component with that kind of state using React Hooks, if you want to keep it functional.

Comment: If that is the case, then you have to move the `visitmyArray` to `this.state` on a `constructor()` as what @TKoL said. Every `render`, the `visitmyArray` will reset back to its initial value. (Correct me if I am wrong). So even if we have changed the `visitmyArray`, the change would not be reflected.

Comment: You'd move the array into `this.state`, and then on button click you'd do a `this.setState` with your updated array. This is the basic React pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Using state, it might look something like this:

```
import React from "react";
import {Button} from 'react-bootstrap';

class VisitComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            visitmyArray: [
                {
                    location:"Indiana",
                    visited:false
                },
                {
                    location:"Illinoi",
                    visited:false
                },
                {
                    location:"Ohio",
                    visited:false
                }
            ]
        };

        this.toggleVisited = this.toggleVisited.bind(this);
    }

    toggleVisited(location) {
        return ev => {
            var locations = this.state.visitmyArray.slice(0);
            var loc = locations.find(a => a.location === location);
            loc.visited = !loc.visited;
            this.setState({visitmyArray:locations})
        }
    }

    render(){
        let {visitmyArray} = this.state;
        return(
            <div>
                {visitmyArray.map((visitedArray, index) => (
                    <div key={index}>
                        <p>{visitedArray.location}</p>
                        <button className={visitedArray.visited ? "visited" : ""} onClick={this.toggleVisited(visitedArray.location)}>Continue</button>
                    </div>
                ))}
            </div>
        )
    }
}


export default VisitComponent
```

Comment: @LalasM there's a syntax issue in there though, be aware of that. you'll have to fix some things around

Comment: @LalasM I updated my answer and tested it, this one works properly and doesn't have syntax errors. The way I defined my button onclick function was wrong before too, now it's right

Answer (score 0):

You can define onClick as:

```
onClick = {() => {
    visitmyArray[index].visited = true
  }
}
```

---

I don't know your use case, but you shouldn't be defining the 'visitmyArray' in the render function. Every time the component renders, it will be redefined, so you should define it elsewhere. For instance,

```
let visitmyArray = [
  {
    location:"Indiana",
    visited:false
  },
  {
    location:"Illinoi",
    visited:false
  },
  {
    location:"Ohio",
    visited:false
  }
]

class VisitComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {...}
}
```

If you want to listen to changes made to the array, you should define it as part of the component's state, like this:

```
let visitmyArray = [
  {
    location:"Indiana",
    visited:false
  },
  {
    location:"Illinoi",
    visited:false
  },
  {
    location:"Ohio",
    visited:false
  }
]

class VisitComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      array: [...]
    }
  }

  render() {...}
}
```

You should change the onClick to use the state's array to create a new array, and then use setState to actually modify it.

Answer (score -1):

after `let visitmyArray` and before `return(` add:

```
markLocationAsVisited = (locationIndex) => {
  this.visitmyArray[locationIndex].visited = true
}
```

and the in Button:

```
<Button onClick={() => markLocationAsVisited(index)}>
```

Comment: This gives me 'marklocationAsVisited' is undefined. Previously i tried similar to this so we are close

Comment: Ok. You are changing the array. But the UI won't be in sync

Comment: @Lalas M - it should probably be  `onClick={() => markLocationAsVisited(index)}`, sorry. @Dupocas - ???

Comment: @pbialy i think we can not use an arrow function like this inside render - not sure though.

Comment: I'm sure you can, try it ;)